# Tic Tac Toe game (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, tic-tac-toe

I have written a tic-tac-toe game in Haskell and was wondering if anyone could provide any hints on how it could be improved

```
import Data.Bits
import System.IO
import Data.List

type Board = (Int, Int) -- the first Int is X's board, the second Int is O's board
data Player = X | O deriving (Eq, Show)

emptyBoard :: Board
emptyBoard = (0, 0)

place :: Board -> Player -> Int -> Maybe Board
place (xb, ob) player pos
  | testBit xb pos || testBit ob pos = Nothing -- position is already occupied
  | player == X = Just (setBit xb pos, ob)
  | player == O = Just (xb, setBit ob pos)

winningMasks :: [Int]
winningMasks = [0o7, 0o70, 0o700, 0o111, 0o222, 0o444, 0o421, 0o124]

winner :: Board -> Maybe Player
winner (xb, ob)
  | any (\mask -> (mask .&. xb) == mask) winningMasks = Just X -- X wins
  | any (\mask -> (mask .&. ob) == mask) winningMasks = Just O -- O wins
  | otherwise = Nothing -- the game is not over yet

data Score = OWins | Tie | XWins deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

minimax :: Board -> Player -> (Score, Maybe Board)
minimax board player
  | winner board == Just X = (XWins, Nothing)
  | winner board == Just O = (OWins, Nothing)
  | popCount (fst board .|. snd board) == 9 = (Tie, Nothing)
  | player == X = maximum [(fst (minimax newBoard O), Just newBoard) | i <- [0..8], Just newBoard <- [place board X i]]
  | player == O = minimum [(fst (minimax newBoard X), Just newBoard) | i <- [0..8], Just newBoard <- [place board O i]]


-- Utility functions

readInt :: String -> Maybe Int
readInt s = case reads s of
              [(x,"")] -> Just x
              _ -> Nothing

readMove :: IO Int
readMove = do
  putStr "Enter move (0-8): "
  hFlush stdout
  input <- getLine
  case readInt input of
    Just move | move `elem` [0..8] -> return move
    _ -> readMove

printBoard :: Board -> IO ()
printBoard (xb, ob) = putStrLn $ unlines (intersperse divider [intersperse '|' [symbol (mask .&. (xb .|. ob)) | mask <- masks j] | j <- [0, 3, 6]])
  where
    symbol 0 = ' '
    symbol m = if m .&. xb /= 0 then 'X'  else 'O'
    masks j = [1 `shiftL` (j + i) | i <- [0..2]]
    divider = replicate 6 '-'

-- Main game loop

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Welcome to tic-tac-toe!"
  putStrLn "You are X, and the computer is O."
  putStrLn "Enter a number between 0 and 8 to make your move."
  playGame emptyBoard X

playGame :: Board -> Player -> IO ()
playGame board player = do
  printBoard board
  case winner board of
    Just X -> putStrLn "You win!"
    Just O -> putStrLn "Computer wins!"
    Nothing -> case player of
      X -> do
        move <- readMove
        case place board X move of
          Just newBoard -> playGame newBoard O
          Nothing -> do
            putStrLn "That square is already occupied."
            playGame board X
      O -> do
        case minimax board O of
          (score, Just newBoard) -> playGame newBoard X
          (score, Nothing) -> putStrLn "Game ends in a tie."
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good and concise, my suggestions are:

In the `winner` function:

```
winner :: Board -> Maybe Player
winner (xb, ob)
  | any (\mask -> (mask .&. xb) == mask) winningMasks = Just X -- X wins
  | any (\mask -> (mask .&. ob) == mask) winningMasks = Just O -- O wins
  | otherwise = Nothing -- the game is not over yet
```

You have repetition, you can write a small helper function `playerWins board player -> bool` and use it twice.

---

In the `minimax` function:

```
minimax :: Board -> Player -> (Score, Maybe Board)
minimax board player
  | winner board == Just X = (XWins, Nothing)
  | winner board == Just O = (OWins, Nothing)
  | popCount (fst board .|. snd board) == 9 = (Tie, Nothing)
  | player == X = maximum [(fst (minimax newBoard O), Just newBoard) | i <- [0..8], Just newBoard <- [place board X i]]
  | player == O = minimum [(fst (minimax newBoard X), Just newBoard) | i <- [0..8], Just newBoard <- [place board O i]]
```

You also have some repetition, but most  importantly the concept that all possible moves must be explored is not evident, so I suggest the helper function `allPossibleMoves board = [newBoard | i <- [0..8], Just newBoard <- [place board O i] ]` to reduce duplication, lower cognitive load and make this fact about the minimax algorithm self-apparent.

---

Regarding minimax, I think that the score should be a number rather than a custom type to allow expanding to games where you cannot see until the end and as such must use heuristics. I think that your current system of a type for the score is incompatible with this extension.

---

I would replace `printBoard :: Board -> IO ()` with `showBoard :: Board -> String` to make it easier to test, you can call `print` in the `main` function with the result of `showBoard`, remember to try to interact with the outside world in as few places as possible to improve testability. On the topic of that function, it looks overcomplicated to be a single function, so try to divide it into two parts (I did not understand it enough to refactor it myself).

I would have done converting to string like this:

- `boardToArray`: to go from bits to an array
- `showBoardArray`: to go from an array to a string

---

Given that you use a bitmask for the board rather than a more high-level representation, you should add comments explaning how to read to and from the data structure, especially when binary masks like these are present: `winningMasks = [0o7, 0o70, 0o700, 0o111, 0o222, 0o444, 0o421, 0o124]`, also if you used binary masks for fun and learning it is ok, but the performance boost from them is not really needed and a normal data-structure would be ok.